# How to have a running footer showing section name alongside a running header showing chapter name?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I want to have a Running Header that will show the Chapter name on top of my page and a Running footer in bottom of the page that show the section name. but indesign choose just the chapter name in both top and bottom of pages.

Comment: Hi Melina, I've edited your question title so people can see what you're asking about. Can you tell us a little more about how you've got things set up currently - in particular, the settings for your running headers and footers, and whether the chapter and section names use different paragraph styles? There's an edit button below your question text